# User input is vowel or consonant: first C steps

Tags: beginner, c

**Background**

Just got started with C and now am testing a few pages and simple problems to get the syntax right.

[On Programiz](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/examples/vowel-consonant) they provide a few very easy problems with solutions.

This program checks if user input is a Vowel or a Consonant or none of those. I solve slightly different, but would be glad to see criticism to details I may not even be aware of.

**Environment**

- For editing the code, I use Vim without any pluggins.
- For testing code I am using [Google's picoc](https://code.google.com/archive/p/picoc/downloads) which is a runtime much like NodeJS or Python's where -in interactive mode- you type C code and it is evaluated right away, so you don't need compilation.

**Code**

The code is commented to reflect what I understand of each step. Double starred comments will produce documentation. Then I mostly use `/* syntax */`.

```
/* importing modules */
#include <stdio.h>/** standard C library for input output.*/
#include <stdbool.h>/** bool data type. Not sure if this is normally used.*/
#include <ctype.h>/** character types, isalpha() function.*/

/** main takes no input, sends no output.*/
void main(void){

  /* set up */
  bool isVowel; char letter; char vowels[] = "aeiouAEIOU";

  /* take user input */
  printf("Insert a character: ");
  scanf("%c", &letter);//Store input at the address of letter.

  /* first check this is an alphabetic character */
  if(!isalpha(letter)) {printf("Not an alphabetic character\n"); }

  int nOfVowels = sizeof(vowels)/sizeof(vowels[0]);

  for(int a=0; a<nOfVowels; a++){

    if(vowels[a]==letter){ isVowel=true; }

  }

  printf("%s\n", isVowel == false ? "Consonant": "Vowel");

}
```

Answer (score 8):

The minimum set of flags you should use with gcc/clang is `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` and fix all warnings:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic main.c
main.c:6:6: warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’ [-Wmain]
    6 | void main(void){ // main takes no input, sends no output.
      |      ^~~~
```

You said

```
/** importing modules */
```

In C world we call this *header files*, not modules like in other
languages such as Python.

You check if input is an alphabetic character

```
if(!isalpha(letter)) {printf("Not an alphabetic character\n"); }
```

but you carry on checking if it's a consonant or vowel which doesn't
make sense:

```
$ ./a.out
Insert a character:    m
Not an alphabetic character
Consonant
```

I think you should exit with error here:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
(...)
  if(!isalpha(letter))
    {
      printf("Not an alphabetic character\n");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
```

You can check exit status in your shell:

```
$ ./a.out
Insert a character:      m
Not an alphabetic character
$ echo $?
1
```

Formatting is a matter of taste but I'd prefer variable definitions
like this

```
bool isVowel; char letter; char vowels[] = "aeiouAEIOU";
```

to be divided into several lines:

```
bool isVowel;
char letter;
char vowels[] = "aeiouAEIOU";
```

You can leave `for(int a=0; a<nOfVowels; a++)` loop right after
finding the first character that is a vowel:

```
  for(int a=0; a<nOfVowels; a++)
    {
      if(vowels[a] == letter)
        {
          isVowel = true;
          break;
        }
    }
```

Not much of a difference performance-wise when there are only 10
elements in `vowels` array but you could see bigger gains if larger
array was used.

Comment: Thank you so much. What would you define `EXIT_FAILURE` to? Also if you could explain the first line that'd be great.

Comment: You don't have to define it on your own, it's defined in platform-specific manner in `stdlib.h`. All gcc options are described in `man gcc`

Answer (score 5):

The only portable return type for `main()` is `int` - although this one function is "magic" in that it doesn't need a `return` statement.  Unlike other functions, we're allowed to just run off the end and the compiler will infer a success status for the program.

We should always check input operations, as even reading a single character may fail (e.g. if we run `./a.out </dev/null`, reading will return the EOF value).  In this case, we need `scanf()` to report exactly 1 successful conversion to be sure that `letter` is assigned a value:

```
printf("Insert a character: ");
fflush(stdout);

if (scanf("%c", &letter) != 1) {
    fputs("Input error\n", stderr);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;      /* defined in <stdlib.h> */
}
```

There's a classic gotcha with the use of `isalpha()`.  It requires an *unsigned* character value, but `char` can be a signed type (e.g. in ISO-8859.1, accented letters can have negative values).  The fix for this is quite simple in this program: just declare `letter` as `unsigned char` instead, and everything else can remain unchanged.

When we search `vowels`, we can simplify a bit.  We know that `sizeof vowels[0]` must be 1 because it's a `char`, and that's the unit of `sizeof`.  Also, we can stop searching (using `break`) as soon as we find a match:

```
for (unsigned a = 0;  a < sizeof vowels;  ++a) {
    if (vowels[a] == letter) {
        isVowel = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

I'd go a bit further, and make this into a function we can call from `main()`:

```
static bool isVowel(unsigned char c)
{
    static const char vowels[] = "aeiouAEIOU";
    for (unsigned a = 0;  a < sizeof vowels;  ++a) {
        if (c == vowels[a]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This function can be further simplified by using the library function `strchr()` (in `<string.h>`) which returns a non-null (true) pointer if the character is found and a null (false) one if not:

```
static bool is_vowel(int c)
{
    static const char vowels[] = "aeiouAEIOU";
    return strchr(vowels, c);
}
```

When we use the result, note that `isVowel == false` is the same as `!isVowel` - or even better, we can swap the order of the conditional to use the positive sense:

```
isVowel ? "Vowel" : "Consonant"
```

---

## Modified code

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static bool is_vowel(int c)
{
    static const char vowels[] = "aeiouAEIOU";
    return strchr(vowels, c);
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("Insert a character: ");
    fflush(stdout);

    unsigned char letter;
    if (scanf("%c", &letter) != 1) {
        fputs("Input error\n", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (isalpha(letter)) {
        const bool is_v = is_vowel(letter);
        printf("%d, %s\n",  is_v,  is_v ? "Vowel" : "Consonant");
    } else {
        printf("Not an alphabetic character\n");
    }
}
```

---

A final note on internationalisation.  Although this is a simple beginner project, it can help demonstrate the problems we have when code interacts with the Real World.  For example, in the word "hymn", `y` acts as a vowel, but the program doesn't understand this.  It also won't recognise vowels such as `à` or `ŵ`.  When writing real programs, it's important to get clear definitions as part of your requirements.

Don't let that complication put you off learning more C, though!

Comment: In `static const char vowels[]`, what benefit does `static` provide?

Comment: It saves on stack and on array initialisation (in a future version, where we call the function more than once) if the compiler isn't smart enough to treat it the same as `const char *const vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";`

Comment: Bug: `bool is_vowel('\0')` returns true.  `strchr(vowels, c)` iterates up to 11 times.  `for (unsigned a = 0;  a < sizeof vowels;  ++a) {` better as `for (unsigned a = 0;  vowels[a];  ++a) {`.  Note: `sizeof vowels` is 11.

Comment: With `unsigned char letter;`, consider `bool is_vowel(unsigned c)` for maximal portability.

Comment: I'll add the usual constraint that anything else is non-portable, @chux.

Answer (score 2):

Bug: **Code considers `'\0'` is a vowel**

`char vowels[] = "aeiouAEIOU";` is an array of size 11, not 10.  `for(int a=0; a<nOfVowels; a++){` iterates up to 11 times.

With `scanf("%c", &letter);`, it is possible, although tricky, to enter the *null character* for `letter`.

Suggest instead:

```
// for(int a=0; a<nOfVowels; a++){
for(int a=0; vowels[a]; a++){
```